# css style like pie chart is not working with jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

[image]
[image]

Form the above two images  css is not working when i append same html code with javascript.

Here is my html code:

```
<tbody id="strengthsTableBody">
<tr>td class='text-center'>
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="inline">
        <div class="easypiechart" 
        data-percent="90" 
        data-line-width="15"
        data-track-color="#eee" 
        data-bar-color="#5cb85c"
        data-scale-color="#fff" 
        data-size="100" 
        data-line-cap='butt'>
            <span class="h3 step">90</span>%
        </div>
    </div>                      
 </div>
</td></tr>
```

Same code i am appending with jquery and make it as a string but it is not working: here is my append script:

```
courceResultsData = 
"<tr><td class='text-center'>
    <div class='text-center'>
        <div class='inline'>
            <div class='easypiechart'
            data-percent='90'
            data-line-width='15'
            data-track-color='#eee'
            data-bar-color='#5cb85c'
            data-scale-color='#fff'
            data-size='100'
            data-line-cap='butt'>
                <span class='h3 step'>90</span>% 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>";

$("#strengthsTableBody" ).append( courceResultsData );
```

Comment: you need CSS for that apart from html/jquery. Where is your CSS. create a fiddle example and don't forget to add CSS there.

Comment: The html string isn't the same as the working example because of the extra `<td>`.

Comment: sorry it is a typo i checked with it but still not working @RobinMackenzie

Comment: @AlivetoDie i am new to CSS and i am totally involved with developmaent can you please help how can call the css properties while append.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't break the data property into different lines. 
Either make in into a single line or add each line into the variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/shiladitya/wu4xgdfh/

```
var courceResultsData = "<tr><td class='text-center'> <div class='text-center'><div class='inline'><div class='easypiechart' data-percent='90' data-line-width='15' data-track-color='#eee' data-bar-color='#5cb85c' data-scale-color='#fff' data-size='100' data-line-cap='butt'> <span class='h3 step'>90</span>% </div> </div> </div></td></tr>";

$("#strengthsTableBody").append(courceResultsData);
```